# Again the routing + pagination issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I will exemplify by code.
Plus, I'm using cake2.0

**this is my routing file:**

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/admin/dashboard', array('prefix'=>'admin', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix'=>'admin'));
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/*', array('prefix'=>'admin'));

Router::connect('/:category_alias/*', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('category_alias')));
```

The last row works the same with or without /:category_alias

**this is the problem**

I'm trying to paginate some products in this route:

http://localhost/main-category/sub-category

The result on the second and third ... links is :

http://localhost/admin/categories/index/main-category/sub-category/page:2
http://localhost/admin/categories/index/main-category/sub-category/page:3
and so on...

I've tried almost every setting for the PaginationController and PaginatorHelper I can imagine.

**the question**
Has anyone dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to modify the URL using the [pagination options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper%3a%3aoptions).

```
<?php
    $this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array('controller' => 'main-category', 'action' => 'sub-category')));
?>
```